# 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Bicycles' [second moderator election](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: jimirings]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice as he learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4849939750322176/0).

Comment: Congratulations Jim!

Comment: The right guy for the job, congrats and good luck!

Comment: Welcome to the moderator team.

Comment: Congratulations and welcome aboard.

Comment: Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Solid candidates overall, pity we couldn't have all of them!